# iterate over array and compare values

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm attempting to iterate over an array and compare to a value, but am running into issues that are stumping me. Here's the code:

```
var cF = ['first','last','email'];
var fFound = 0;
cj(this).children('.section').each(function(f){
  var fId = cj(this).attr('class');
  fId = fId.replace('-section', '');
  console.log('fId: ',fId);
  cj.each(cF, function( cFi, cFv ){
    console.log('cFv: ',cFv);
    if ( cFv == fId ) {
      console.log('found!');
      fFound = 1;
    }
  });
  console.log('fFound: ',fFound);
});
```

Basically what I'm doing is searching through a series of divs (passed with 'this'), retrieving the class name, stripping the suffix to the class, and then comparing it with my cF array. If found, I want to set fFound to 1 (it's my flag to indicate the value is present).

Originally I was using jQuery.inArray() but wasn't having much luck. When I send fId and cFv to the console -- they match -- but the comparison doesn't recognize them as matching.

Comment: Can you show us the log of:
console.log('fId: ',fId);

I have this feeling that it needs a tolower() or a trim().

Comment: Could you include the relevat HTML as well?

Comment: You might have to trim the class attribute value as it´s a whitespace separated string. But I think you should stick with the $.inArray approach to keep your own loops to a minimum.

Comment: Stefan actually had the key piece. The value pulled from the html class had a leading space that wasn't visible in the console and was preventing the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cj.each(cF, function( cFi, cFv ){
    console.log('cFv: ',cFv);
    if ( $.inArray( fId, cF )  > -1 ) {
      console.log('found!');
      fFound = 1;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**iterate over array and compare values**

```
var cF = ['first','last','email'];
var bla = 'anything'
var fFound = 0;

for (j in cF) {
    if (bla.indexOf(cF[j]) > -1) {
        fFound = 1;
    }
}
```

ops... you want jQuery... scratch that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cF = ['first','last','email'];
var fFound = 0;
cj(this).children('.section').each(function(f){       
  var fId = cj(this).attr('class');
  fFound = 0; // reset 
  fId = fId.replace('-section', '').trim();
  console.log('fId: ',fId);
  if( $.inArray( fId, cF ) !== -1 ) {
      console.log('found!');          
   }
   console.log('fFound: ',fFound);
});
```